# Dealing with Unicode characters in NSArray after parsing a JSON feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unicode

I've googled this to death and can't find the correct answer. Maybe I'm not phrasing the question correctly. I have a web service that provides a JSON feed. I log in and authenticate my username and password then parse some of the JSON feed and insert it into an NSArray as per below.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
self.urlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSLog(@"DID RECEIVE RESPONSE");
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
//NSLog(@"THE RAW DATA IS %@", data);
[self.urlData appendData:data];

//NSData
NSString *strRes = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"LOGGING THE DATA STRING %@", strRes);

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;



self.parsedJSONFeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.urlData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

self.titleList = [_parsedJSONFeed valueForKeyPath:@"response.page_items.title"];
self.dateList = [_parsedJSONFeed valueForKeyPath:@"response.page_items.date"];

//NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

if (jsonParsingError) {

    NSLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);

} else {
    //NSLog(@"PARSED OBJECT %@", parsedObject);

    //NSLog(@"OBJECT: %@", [object class]);

}

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

So now "self.titleList" is an NSArray that contains text but the unicode characters have also passed through from the JSON feed. Is there a way to prevent this happening, or convert those unicode characters before/after parsing the JSON feed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The authentication is of no interest; remove the code that does that from your question and post an example of the characters causing a problem.  I know that the \ character will be involved in the output somewhere and it's important to understand (for us as well as you) if this character is in the JSON or added by whatever mechanism you are using the view the character data.  Therefore please find some way to demonstrate that to us (and yourself).  Apart from that, +1 for a well structured question.

Comment: Good point. I've removed the authentication code. Basically any special characters in the NSArray is replaced by the comparable Unicode code. i.e. Hyphens, double/single quotes etc. If I NSLog the the (NSDictionary) _parsedJSONFeed or (NSArray) self.titleList they both contain the Unicode code and not the actual special character. If I view the JSON directly in a browser there are no Unicode numbers, they special characters are correctly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anybody lands on this page with the same problem. In fact, they were HTML encoded unicode entities that were causing the problem.

Import this: https://github.com/Koolistov/NSString-HTML category into your project and send your NSString's to the relevant method. All working fine here now.